# Is libmircommon5 safe to remove?

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu

On Lubuntu 16.04 LTS I noticed today, that `sudo apt-get autoremove` wants to remove the `libmircommon5` package.

I'm a bit surprised by this, since I haven't installed or uninstalled software (except for updates, of course) since a while, so I can't really understand why `autoremove` is now coming up with this.

Because I had false positives with `autoremove` in the past and according to [the documentation](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libmircommon5) it sounds like the package could be important, I wanted to ask here, if anyone knows more about this.

Comment: In general, this may be because of an update which made this deprecated. In fact, this is probably the most likely thing, that this was a dependency which was necessary for some application, and now the application no longer needs it. Personally, I would trust `autoremove`, but maybe someone else here can be more specific on this than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, today I found the time to make a backup and then I just tried what happens when I remove the package and reboot.

So far, the package manager does not complain about any broken dependencies and I haven't recognized anything not working that was working before, so it seems the package is safe to remove if `autoremove` starts advising it after one of the more recent updates to Ubuntu.